# ArcGIS API For Javascript - Custom DynamicMapServiceLayer Image Being Distorted In Map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am having some trouble with a custom DynamicMapServiceLayer that I hope someone can either help me out with, or explain what is happening...

On the application I am currently working on, there is a requirement for a 'HeatMap' style layer.  Since I have to support all the way back to IE 7 - using HTML5 canvas solutions are not possible.  For that reason, I have created a Server Object Extension that renders that heat map at server, and returns an image that should work in any browser.

The SOE is working great.  However, the image that gets added to map is a bit 'smooshed'[image].

But the raw image (same request as above - just grabbed this out of Google Developer Tools Network tab) getting returned by the SOE does not show this distortion.[image]

Why is Javascript API doing this - I thought it would just display the raw image?

Comment: Is the heatmap image being created in the same datum/projection that the web app is shown in?

Comment: Yes, everything is same projection.  Again, look at the raw image returned from SOE - no distortion.  The 'smooshing' happens sometime between loading into DynamicMapService layer and display in map.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot.  I had the dimensions reversed at the server, so the image size that was being returned was different than what was requested, and the smooshing was the result of scaling that image.

Once i corrected dimensions - everything looks perfect.